# Converting this sum to integral (possible?). The goal is to get error function

Tags: fourier-analysis, riemann-sum, error-function, heat-equation

The solution to the heat equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
with boundary conditions and ini condition as followed:
$$u(0\ or\ 1, t)=0\qquad u(x,0)=1$$

Fourier transform-typed solution is as followed:
$$u(x,t)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-(2k-1)^2 \pi ^2 t} \sin[(2k-1)\pi x]}{2k-1}$$

I know that I need to convert the $sin$ function to exponential but then I don't know how to convert in into integral form, for short time. From the integral, we should get error function of some sort. Anyone?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can try [something like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Plana_formula) after you check whether it satisfies its math-conditions. I don't think it will add any thing helpful to your question.